# Quicksort from recursion to iteration using the general method of stack

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, recursion, iteration

I have a recursive quick sort implementation in C and I want to convert it to an iterative one using stack.

This is my implementation in C:

```
int random_partition(int* arr, int start, int end) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int random_pivot = rand() % (start - end) + start;
    swap(&arr[random_pivot], &arr[end]);
    int pivot = arr[end], pivot_index = start;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (arr[i] <= pivot) {
            swap(&arr[pivot_index], &arr[i]);
            pivot_index++;
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[pivot_index], &arr[end]);
    return pivot_index;
}

void quick_sort(int* arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end)  {
        int pivot_index = random_partition(arr, start, end);
        quick_sort(arr, start, pivot_index - 1);
        quick_sort(arr, pivot_index + 1, end);
    }
}
```

This is something I did, but when popping I don't do anything, because in recursion that s what we do.

```
void quick_sort_iter(int* arr, int start, int end) {
  stack* s = create_stack(n);
  int pivot_index = random_partition(arr, start, end);
  int p = pivot_index;
  while (start < pivot_index) {
    pivot_index = random_partition(arr, start, end);
    push(s, start);
    push(s, pivot_index--);
  }
  pivot_index = p;
  while (pivot_index < end) {
    push(s, pivot_index++);
    push(s, end);
    pivot_index = random_partition(arr, start, end);
  }
  while(!is_empty(s)) {
    int e = pop(s);
    int s = pop(s);
    // do nothing, because in recursion the return doesn't do anything
  }
  return arr;
}
```

I am first just asking about if this is the way to go or how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two loops will only create partitions that either start at the extreme left (at `start`) or at end at the extreme right (at `end`), but a correct algorithm would also create partitions that are not bounding at either extreme end of the array.

To achieve that, first push the complete array range on the stack, and then in one loop, pop a range from the stack, and if it has at least tow elements, partition it, and push both generated partition ranges back on the stack. Continue doing that until there is nothing in the stack:

```
void quick_sort_iter(int* arr, int size) {
    stack* s = create_stack(2*size);
    push(s, 0);
    push(s, size-1);
    while (!is_empty(s)) {
        int end = pop(s);
        int start = pop(s);
        if (start < end) {
            int pivot_index = random_partition(arr, start, end);
            push(s, start);
            push(s, pivot_index - 1);
            push(s, pivot_index + 1);
            push(s, end);
        }
    }
}
```

Some remarks:

- This function only needs the size of the array as argument. `start` and `end` are managed locally in the loop. So adjust the call from your `main` to only pass the array pointer and the array size.
- The function is `void` and should not return the array. The array is sorted in-place, just like the recursive implementation does.
- You passed `n` as stack size, but it was not clear what value that `n` represented. Here I have used the double of the array size (as each time we push a pair of indices) as size for the stack, which is enough to cover for the worst case scenario. As you have a random pivot selection the expected space use of the stack is O(log). As noted in comments, you can make that the maximum (2log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub> entries) by putting the larger partition on the stack first.

Comment: If one makes sure to push the longer partition first in each cycle, then the needed stack size can be limited to O(log n).  That's worlds better than O(sqrt n) -- small enough that you can comfortably use a fixed-size automatic array for your stack.

Comment: Thanks, @John, that is a good remark. I have updated the answer slightly, as it had some inaccuracies, and referenced your comment.